# is it possible to create a list of cards with multiple buttons in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I looked for open codes or nuget that could help me with this question, I would like to create a list of Cards like these in the images, where I could have several click events, but could get the id of the item that fills the card.
Eu tentei com CollectionView, porem não consigo pegar a id do item do card, nem com uma label e o x:Name atribuído a essa label.
Segue o cod xaml que criei

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

<ContentPage.Resources>

<converters:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImage" />

</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>





<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Image.GestureRecognizers HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30">

</Image.GestureRecognizers>

```
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="5,25,10,0" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                    <Frame  BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="440" WidthRequest="330" HasShadow="True" Padding="5" Margin="0">
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Label x:Name="lblMessage" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Rep:" IsVisible="false"></Label>

                                            <StackLayout HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="320" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                                <Frame HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="320" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                                                    <ImageButton Source="{Binding ImagemVideo, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImage}}" Aspect="AspectFill"  Margin="0" Clicked="Video_Clicked"/>
                                                </Frame>

                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <Frame BorderColor="Transparent"  BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                                <Label Grid.Column="0"                                    
                                               TextColor="#000000"
                                               Text="{Binding NomeTreino}"
                                               FontAttributes="None"
                                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                               Margin="8,0,10,10"
                                               FontSize="Medium"/>
                                            </Frame>
                                            <Frame BorderColor="LightGray" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                                <Label Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="{Binding Descricao}"/>
                                            </Frame>

                                            <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="5,5">



                                                <Grid Visual="Material">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Visual="Material" Grid.Column="0" BorderColor="LightGray">
                                                        <StackLayout >
                                                            <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Carga:"></Label>
                                                            <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Text="{Binding cargaInicial}"></Label>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </Frame>


                                                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderColor="LightGray">
                                                        <StackLayout >
                                                            <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Séries:"></Label>
                                                            <Label   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding serie1}"></Label>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </Frame>

                                                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BorderColor="LightGray">
                                                        <StackLayout >
                                                            <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Rep:"></Label>
                                                            <Label  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding repeticao1}"></Label>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </Frame>

                                                    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderColor="LightGray">
                                                        <StackLayout >
                                                            <!--<Image  Source="prod.jpg"></Image>-->
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding tempoIntervalo}" ></Label>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </Frame>


                                                    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderColor="LightGray">
                                                        <StackLayout >
                                                            <ImageButton  BackgroundColor="White" Source="Checkblue.png" Aspect="Fill"  HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20"  Margin="0" Clicked="BtnCheck_Clicked"/>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </Frame>

                                                </Grid>
                                            </StackLayout>


                                        </StackLayout>

                                    </Frame>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Do you have a more specific question?  The XAML you posted doesn’t contain any buttons or gesture recognizers so it’s unclear what sort of click events you want to generate or how you want to handle them.

Comment: Hello Jason, I wanted to do the same as the image I posted, it has 6 buttons on the card, to add weight to training, notes, finish it, change training, time and view the video

Comment: What is your question?  What are you stuck on?  You've already built a UI, do you know how to add buttons to it?  What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: In my code that I attached the CollectionView I can only select via SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="CvCategorias_SelectionChanged", at least that's how I know it, I'm new to xamarin development

Comment: add Buttons to your UI and then assign commands or event handlers to each button

Comment: Do you have any example I can follow? In the code there is an ImageButton with the Clicked command, but I cannot retrieve the training id of this card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your event handler

```
protected void ButtonClicked(object Sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    var item = (MyClassName)btn.BindingContext;

    // now you can access an property on item that you need
}
```